# How to check at runtime if a NamedNativeQuery was declared

Tags: java, hibernate, named-query

In Hibernate, is there a way to check if a given `@NamedNativeQuery` exists before calling:
`Session.getNamedQuery("queryName");`

I am composing the name of the Query at runtime, so I need a way to find if it exists, in order to avoid the following exception:

> MappingException: Named query not known: queryName

Answer (score -1):

Use method `getNamedParameters()` to check the names of all named parameters of the query.

Update: Currently the only way to check whether a named query with a given name exists is calling  `EntityManager.createNamedQuery(…)` . The non-presence of a query can be expressed by throwing an exception.

Comment: I need to check if the @NamedNativeQuery has been declared, not the parameters

Comment: Is it okay to look for the `@NamedNativeQuery` / `@NamedNativeQueries` annotation? It's available at runtime. A hacky solution though.